# Opera: Downloaderror when I click run. Save works

Tags: 64-bit, download, opera

Stackoverflow sent me here, so i hope you can help me ;)

Every time I want to download something, I get an error on this download if I click the "Run"-Button on the download dialogue. I tested or rather experienced it on trying to download Opera itself, Firefox, mySql Community Server, Grails and some random stuff.
All using the built-in Download-Manager

Only thing I've changed recently is my Windows Version. From Win 7 Professional 32-Bit Ger to Win 7 Prof 64-Bit Eng.

Is there a difference with Eng or German Versions I don't know about or is it the change from 32 to 64 bit ?!

Thanks in advance